# Using 'assign' for binding module ports

Tags: verilog, hdl

I'm new to Verilog and still learning it, but the first think I get about that language is that it's all about ports interconnections. So, I naively wrote the following code

```verilog
module mult4(input  wire [3:0] x, y,
             output wire [7:0] z)
    sum8 sh, sl, ss;
    assign sl.x = (y[0] ? x : 0),
           sl.y = (y[1] ? x : 0) << 1,
           sh.x = (y[2] ? x : 0) << 2,
           sh.x = (y[3] ? x : 0) << 3,
           ss.x = sl.z,
           ss.y = sh.z,
           sl.cin = 0,
           sh.cin = 0,
           ss.cin = 0,
           z = ss.z;
endmodule
```

and it wasn't going to work at all. Here `sum8` is a mere 8-bit adder with a the following signature:

```
module sum8(input  wire       cin,   // carry-in bit
            input  wire [7:0] x, y,  // operands
            output wire       cout,  // carry-out bit
            output wire [7:0] z);    // result
```

Of course, I can rewrite this code to make it compile, but I would like to know another thing. Is there a way to achieve a similar look-and-feel in Verilog, or the only place where I can define port's mapping is inside the parentheses after the module name? If so, are there reasons for that? Do other HDLs have a feature like I want?

Comment: Can you show what functionality you are looking for? i.e. What is `sum8` supposed to represent? And how does ss.z get a value?

Comment: What is `sum8`?

Comment: @dave_59: sorry for the long delay, I've just updated the question. But it's not about how the concrete module works, but why I can read from `module.port`, but cannot assign to it. Maybe the question itself isn't so good in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing would be the `interface` construct in SystemVerilog. It would look something like this:

```
interface adder8_itf;
  wire             cin;   // carry-in bit
  wire [7:0] x, y;  // operands
  wire             cout;  // carry-out bit
  wire [7:0] z;     // result
endinterface 
module mult4(input  wire [3:0] x, y,
             output wire [7:0] z);
    adder8_itf sh(), sl(), ss();
    sum8 i1(sh), i2(sl), i3(ss);
    assign sl.x = (y[0] ? x : 0),
           sl.y = (y[1] ? x : 0) << 1,
           sh.x = (y[2] ? x : 0) << 2,
           sh.x = (y[3] ? x : 0) << 3,
           ss.x = sl.z,
           ss.y = sh.z,
           sl.cin = 0,
           sh.cin = 0,
           ss.cin = 0,
           z = ss.z;
endmodule
module sum8 (adder8_itf itf);
   assign {itf.cout,itf.z} = itf.x +itf.y;
endmodule
```

Though, this is probably more work just so you can organize your port assignments a different way.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is only two way to connect ports in Verilog, by name or by order. You can take a look at [this article](http://www.vlsifacts.com/port-mapping-for-module-instantiation-in-verilog/) that explains the ways to do it.

You can however find something similar to what you are describing in VHDL with [the `port map` directive.](http://amouf.chez.com/syntaxe.htm#PORT_MAP)